# Struggling with simple AWS AppSync Batch Resolver

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

I'm new to AppSync, and I'm having a little trouble wrapping my head around the VTL resolvers. I'm trying to get what should be a pretty basic resolver function to work. The functionality I am trying to get working is user favorites. In my app users can make posts, and other users can favorite/save posts. I want a user to be able to look at all of the posts they have saved.

The AppSync schema that is relevant is as follows:

```
type User {
id: ID!
...other fields
favorites: [Post!]
}



type Post{
    id: ID!
    title: String!
    description: String!
    owner: ID!
}
```

In the dynamoDB table called UserTable I have a column called favorites which is of type StringSet. The items in this set are id's (which are also primary keys) of posts found in PostTable.

An example of the favorites list is as follows

```
favorites[ "021612bf-61ed-418f-a913-3dc0e63ca952", "0687c0e8-5f87-4315-b383-908dab0e258f" ]
```

I'm attempting to attach the resolver to the

```
favorites: [Post!]
```

field under the User type. I have gotten a query to return a single post with this resolver, but the favorites column in the UserTable was a single string and NOT a list.

```
{
    "version" : "2017-02-28",
    "operation" : "Scan",
    "filter" : {
        "expression" : "id = :id",
        "expressionValues" : {
            ":id" : { "S" : "$ctx.source.favorites" }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Scan can only filter on one expression value at a time; `ctx.source.favorites` resolves to `"[021612bf-61ed-418f-a913-3dc0e63ca952, 0687c0e8-5f87-4315-b383-908dab0e258f]"` which won't be understood by the Scan expression. Perhaps you need to use a BatchGetItem operation in your resolver template? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-mapping-template-reference-dynamodb.html#aws-appsync-resolver-mapping-template-reference-dynamodb-batch-get-item

Comment: Have you tried turning on Logging? You'll be able to see the result of each invocation for each resolver in your schema, which might be the best way to debug this.